# Formatting html table content for use with iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have an iframe whose height is 100px and width is 450px. I am trying to format an html table so that it has the following layout:

```
_______
|     | GREY_TEXT: BLUE_TEXT
|     | Hyperlink
| img | SOME_TEXT ~ DATE
|     | BLACK_TEXT
-------
```

where the img is 100 high by 80 wide

The problem I'm having is that the GREEN_Text sometimes ends up above the image in the iframe depending on how long the hyperlink is. the black text length shouldn't matter as it can be cut off and I'm not putting vertical scrolls.

my code is:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<table height="100" width="450">
<tr>
<td height="100" width="80">
<table style="margin-top:50px">
<img align="top" src="myPicPath.png" height="100" width="120">
</table>
</td>
<td height="100" width="200">
<table height="25" width="387" style="margin-top:-20px">
<tr>
<td width="20">
<p style="color:#A0A0A0; font-family:arial; font-size:12px;"> GREY_TEXT:</p>
</td>
<td  width="86">
<p style="color:blue; font-family:arial; font-size:12px;">BLUE_TEXT
</td>
<td width="0">
<!--left Blank-->
</td>
<td width="205" style="text-align:right;">
<p style="color:#A0A0A0; font-family:arial; font-size:12px;"> SOME_TEXT | DATE
</p>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table height="25" style="margin-top:-20px">
<tr>
<td>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table height="50" width="370">
<a style="font-family:arial; font-size:15px;" target="_blank" href="http://SOMESITE.com"> HyperLink</a>
<p align="justify" style="font-family:arial; font-size:13px;">BLACK TEXT
</p>
</table>
</table>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You tagged JavaScript -- where's your JavaScript?

Comment: thanks for pointing out the miss tag, but can you provide any feedback regarding the question?? thanks ...

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing for email?
You need a proper indent where you use table, otherwise, it just become a mess:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <table height="100" width="325">
            <tr>
                <td height="100" width="120"><img align="top" src="myPicPath.png" height="100" width="120" style="display: block;"></td>
                <td height="100" width="205">
                    <table height="25" width="205" style="margin-top:-20px">
                        <tr><td><span style="color:#A0A0A0; font-family:arial; font-size:12px;"> GREY_TEXT:</span> <span style="color:blue; font-family:arial; font-size:12px;">BLUE_TEXT</span></td></tr>
                        <tr><td><a style="font-family:arial; font-size:15px;" target="_blank" href="http://SOMESITE.com"> HyperLink</a></td></tr>
                        <tr><td><span style="color:#A0A0A0; font-family:arial; font-size:12px;"> SOME_TEXT | DATE</span></td></tr>
                        <tr><td><span style="font-family:arial; font-size:13px;">BLACK TEXT</span></td></tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct, you want your image to always hug the top of your left column, no matter how long your right column is. This jsfiddle shows this behavior: http://jsfiddle.net/smy8z/

The key there is `style="vertical-align: top;"` in the `<td>` that contains your image.

I would advise going about this in a different way altogether. Doing layout with tables, positioning with attributes, and styling with inline styles are all substandard practices in the modern web. Typically, you would use HTML elements that make the most sense for your content, so tables would be used for data that is tabular (think of an Excel spreadsheet). Past that, you would keep your styles and layout rules in a separate CSS file. This will separate your responsibilities (general layout in html, specific styling in css), and will keep your HTML clean and legible.